# which viewpager settings should be set?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My app has 3 tabs: tablyout, viewpager with fragmentPager adapter. I have a  problem: first tab to second tab to third tab and back to first tab fragment restarted.

```
TextTabAdapter adapter = new TextTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 1, fragmentList, tabTitleList); 
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: post your activity class

Comment: TextTabAdapter adapter = new TextTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 1, fragmentList, tabTitleList);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextTabAdapter adapter = new TextTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 1, fragmentList, tabTitleList); 
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
//set viewpager off screens, By default , it is one. 
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabTitleList.size());
```